# ClassLoaders in Java

Tags: java, class, classloader

Class loaders are hierarchical. Child class loaders ask parent to load the class, if parent is not able to then child loads the class, there by maintaining uniqueness. All classes loaded by parent are accessible to child class loaders, but opposite is not true. Question arised in my mind: Child asked the parent to load the class, but due to some issue, parent was not able to load, so child loads it in the JVM. At some point later parent needs that class and obviously parent cannot see what child class loaders' classes are loaded in JVM, so would the parent too loads that class in the JVM? What happens to the uniqueness of the same class? How is the issue resolved? Any good pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> parent was not able to load, so child loads it in the JVM

Parent might not be able to load the class due to two reasons: class was physically not found or it expected some transient failure. In the former case `ClassLoader` will throw a `ClassNotFoundException` and that will never change. In the latter, a different exception will be thrown from the parent, interrupting child class loader. So such situation should never occur.

> What happens to the uniqueness of the same class?

Not in this case, but technically this is possible, especially in application servers with complex class loader hierarchies. Essentially two class loaders can load the same class, which are incompatible (you can get `ClassCastException`).

Answer (score 0):

In your case there would be two classes in the JVM with the same name but different `Class` instances. These classes are considered different in all aspects. When you try to assign references "cross classloader" then you will get an excpetion like

```
Cannot cast class Foo to class Foo
```

This is not a theoretical problem - this kind of exception is seen every now and then in the Java EE/EJB domain.

Answer (score 0):

Classes that are equals has to be equals in all the following:
1. The name of the class should be the same
2. The name of the package should be the same
3. The classLoader that load the class has to be the same.

so classes that are not loaded by the same classLoader are not the same class!
This way you can import two jars that are different versions in the same application server, this is done by different classLoaders.

hope it helps...